# Alternative optimization algorithms for lmer

Tags: r, optimization, lme4, mixed-models

The function `lmer` in the `lme4` package uses by default `bobyqa` from the `minqa` package as  optimization algorithm.

According to the following post https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2013q1/020075.html, it is possible to use also the other optimization algorirthms in the `minqa` package

How can one use `uobyqa` or `newuoa` as optimization algorithm for `lmer`?

```
library(lme4)
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy, control=lmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa"))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use `newuoa` nor `uobyqa` because neither allows for constraints on the parameters. From `?lmerControl` (emphasis added)

> Any minimizing function **that allows box constraints** can be used provided that it
>
> (1) takes input parameters ‘fn’ (function to be optimized), ‘par’ (starting parameter values), ‘lower’ (lower bounds) and ‘control’ (control parameters, passed through from the ‘control’ argument) and
>
> (2) returns a list with (at least) elements ‘par’ (best-fit
>                 parameters), ‘fval’ (best-fit function value), ‘conv’
>                 (convergence code, equal to zero for successful
>                 convergence) and (optionally) ‘message’ (informational
>                 message, or explanation of convergence failure).

The `b` at the beginning of "bobyqa" stands for "bound" (as in constrained), I assume the `u` in the other algorithms similarly stands for "unconstrained". You can check out this file for some machinery to (re)fit the same model with a bunch of different optimizers:

```
allFit <- system.file("utils", "allFit.R", package="lme4")
file.show(allFit)
```

The list of *all* optimizers I currently know about that allow box constraints and don't require an explicit gradient function to be specified (required for most of the bound-constrained optimizers in the `optimx` package), as shown in the file above, is

- BOBYQA (`minqa` and `nloptr` package implementations)
- Nelder-Mead (`lme4`, `nloptr`, and `dfoptim` package implementations)
- `nlminb` from base R (from the Bell Labs PORT library)
- `L-BFGS-B` from base R, via `optimx` (Broyden-Fletcher-Goldfarb-Shanno, via Nash)

In addition to these, which are built in to `allFit.R`, you can use the `COBYLA` or subplex optimizers from `nloptr`: see `?nloptwrap`. There's another implementation of subplex in the `subplex` package: there may be a few others I've missed.