# Error in lme4::allFit() -- no applicable method for 'isGLMM'

Tags: r, logistic-regression, lme4

I'm hitting a confusing error while trying to run the `lme4::allFit()` using some built-in parallelization. I fit an initial model `m0`, which uses a larger dataframe `ckDF` (n = 265,623 rows) to model a binary response to a number of categorical and continuous predictors in a logistic framework with a random intercept for year.

I'm interested in determining whether different optimizers yield different results, following some recommendations I've found online (e.g. by @BenBolker [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25142457/alternative-optimization-algorithms-for-lmer)). My data is fairly large and takes ~20 minutes to run usually, so I'm hoping to use the `parallel` and `ncpus` parameters of `allFit()` to speed it up a bit. Here's my relevant code:

```
require(lme4)
require(parallel)

m0 <- glmer(returned ~ 1 + barge + site + barge:site + 
            (run + rearType + basin)^2 + 
            (tdg + temp + holdingTime)^2 +
            (1|year), 
            data = ckDF, family = 'binomial',
            control = glmerControl(optimizer='bobyqa', 
                                   optCtrl = list(maxfun = 1e5)))
af1 <- allFit(m0, parallel = 'multicore', ncpus = detectCores())
```

Upon doing this, I encounter the following error:

> Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
>     7 nodes produced errors; first error: no applicable method for 'isGLMM' applied to an object of class "list"

Any ideas? It seems to me that when it constructs a bunch of nodes, somehow some of them don't import the `lme4` package and thus do not recognize `isGLMM()`; but I don't know why `allFit()` would do this, since it's from `lme4()`. I tried looking under the hood and altering the function for my own `allFit()` package, but ran into other errors.

Any help would be appreciated. R Version: 3.6.1; lme4 Version: 1.1-21; platform: Windows 10 64-bit

Comment: I wonder is you need to use `parallel="snow"` on windows? (noting the help for allFit says to run `clusterEvalQ(cl,library("lme4"))` first)

Comment: I agree with the @user20650's suggestion. "multicore" uses "mclapply", which is not generally available on Windows. Should we add more documentation to the `allFit` help page?

Comment: Yes.  I'd like to see if the OP responds (I don't currently have access to a Windows system for testing ...)

Comment: Thanks @user20650 & @Ben Bolker -- I dove into a little more after posting and realized that `snow` would have to be what I used for any parallel processing in Windows. I'll test it again here and let you know if that resolves the issue (takes a while to run on my machine). I think even a comment suggesting 'snow' should be used for Windows users in the `allFit` documentation would be helpful for newbies like me.

Comment: I guess one confusing bit is that the documentation reads that the `cl` parameter is optional, but based on the note, if `parallel = "snow"`, you would actually have to define your own cluster so that you're able to run `clusterEvalQ(cl,library("lme4"))` on your predefined cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @user20650 & @Ben Bolker for the tips in comments above -- it worked and I was able to get `allFit()` to run as expected, by ensuring I use `parallel = "snow"` in my function call since I'm running in Windows. Just posting the edited code here for anyone else who finds this useful:

```
require(lme4); require(snow)

# Define initial model (switched to defaults here)
m0 <- glmer(returned ~ 1 + barge + site + barge:site + 
            (run + rearType + basin)^2 + 
            (tdg + temp + holdingTime)^2 +
            (1|year), 
            data = ckDF, family = 'binomial')

# Set up cluster for running allFit()
optCls <- makeCluster(detectCores()-1, type = "SOCK")
clusterEvalQ(optCls,library("lme4"))
clusterExport(optCls, "ckDF")

# Use allFit() to look at differences in optimizers
system.time(af1 <- allFit(m0, parallel = 'snow', 
                          ncpus = detectCores()-1, cl=optCls))
stopCluster(optCls)
```

Ended up taking ~40 minutes using 11 cores on my machine.